# How to perform a groupby and select unique in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a flights dataset containing "UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME", "MONTH_YEAR", "ROUTE" and other attributes such as passenger count, etc. which are not relevant to me in this case. Here is a sample (There are many other carriers and date ranges to 2017):

```
           UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME MONTH_YEAR    ROUTE
2512    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  OGG-HNL
2648    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSW
2649    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSW
2650    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSW
3104    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  HNL-SFO
3470    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  SFO-HNL
3482    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  SFO-OGG
4522    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  OGG-HNL
5076    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  RSW-IND
5077    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  RSW-IND
5078    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  RSW-IND
5296    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  RSW-IND
5297    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  RSW-IND
5371    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  SFO-HNL
5389    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  SFO-OGG
....
```

I want to be able to groupby "UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME", "MONTH_YEAR", "ROUTE" in this sequence in Python. I have written this:

```
carrier_groups = df.groupby(["UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME","MONTH_YEAR","ROUTE])
```

This returns me a DataFrameGroupBy object which I can use for iterating to perform some calculations on route data -- is there anyway I can choose not to aggregate the data (for the rest of the columns) and just select the unique routes in this groupby function? These 3 rows should be only selected as 1.

```
2648    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSW
2649    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSW
2650    ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSW
```

I would like to iterate this set of DataFrame grouped by "UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME", "MONTH_YEAR" such that I have :

```
for each group of DataFrame:
    I have a subset of df which I can run a function on ROUTE to get some results
```

Comment: Are you looking for `pivot`. Do add the expected output?

Comment: IIUC, is this what you want: df[['UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME','MONTH_YEAR','ROUTE']].groupby(['UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME','MONTH_YEAR']).ROUTE.unique()

Comment: @Bharathshetty I have added some examples and expected intermediary output.

Comment: @Mokshyam This only returns me the routes, I would like the other 2 columns as well!

Comment: You need not group by, just drop the duplicates in the dataframe using df.drop_duplicates()

Comment: Exactly, you need `df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 3):

No grouping is necessary. Just drop the dupes in the dataframe using:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME','MONTH_YEAR','ROUTE'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) your function (only some sample function, because no information about it):

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    #apply your function 
    #some sample function 
    x['ROUTE'] = x['ROUTE'] + 'a'
    return x 

df = df.drop_duplicates(['UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME','MONTH_YEAR','ROUTE'])
df = df.apply(func, axis=1)
print (df)
         UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME MONTH_YEAR     ROUTE
2512  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  OGG-HNLa
2648  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  IND-RSWa
3104  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  HNL-SFOa
3470  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  SFO-HNLa
3482  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  SFO-OGGa
4522  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  OGG-HNLa
5076  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     2-1990  RSW-INDa
5296  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  RSW-INDa
5371  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  SFO-HNLa
5389  ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA     3-1990  SFO-OGGa
```

Comment: whats the need of  `+'a'` ?

Comment: sample function only ;)